# Meaning of Without Prejudice

Tags: legalese, signage

What does the term

> "without prejudice"

mean in a legal sense (ie near your signature or credentials on a document or contract - binding or not) as opposed to the non-legal meaning?

EDIT: Just to expand this slightly to cover an obvious ambiguity:  Does it depend (ie have a different meaning) if the phrase is used by the creator of the document (on the top of the document perhaps), as opposed to the person who would sign the document (and append this phrase to the signature area)

Comment: It depends on context, but they're all [general reference](https://www.google.ie/search?q=%22without+prejudice%22) and all really the non-legal meaning in terms of that specific context. On a document it would generally mean that a communication made in an attempt to reach a settlement is claiming the privilege that if you refuse the settlement you cannot then raise the offer in court. E.g. if you owe someone €50,000 and they offer to settle for €40,000 and you refuse you can't then turn around in court and present it as proof that they should be happy to only receive €40,000.

Comment: Thanks @JonHanna this qualifies as an answer really, very helpful

Comment: Well, while I do think the question should be closed as a general reference question, there's no harm in closing **and** being helpful at the same time.

Comment: I think this question should stay open, as there are a variety of ways you can use the phrase 'without prejudice' - perhaps at the top of the page, following a signature, etc.  In other words it can be written by the creator of the document and / or the receiver of the document.  I will expand the question a little

Comment: There are indeed a variety of ways, but you can just look them up, which makes them off-topic by the rules of the site.

Comment: Well I have modified the Question to be explicit, is that OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *Black's Law Dictionary* (1968):

> ***Without prejudice.*** Where an offer or admission is made "without prejudice," or a motion is denied or a bill in equity dismissed "without prejudice," it is meant as a declaration that no rights or privileges of the party concerned are to be considered as thereby waived or lost, except in so far as may be expressly conceded or decided.

One legal situation in which the wording "without prejudice" often comes up involves a plaintiff who pursues judicial relief for some alleged wrong, but fails to frame the suit in a form that presents the court with a justiciable issue; in short, the petition fails to state a claim for which, by law, relief can be granted.

In such an instance, a judge might throw out the suit and tell the plaintiff not to come back; or the judge might dismiss the case *without prejudice*, meaning that the plaintiff has the right to amend the complaint or suit to make it conform with legal requirements. Thus, the plaintiff's flawed original petition has not caused the plaintiff to forfeit any rights for relief under law.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.wisewouldmahony.com.au/index.php?id=308) is the first Google hit I got on this and it states the usage very well.

When used on correspondence (or more rarely verbal communication) that is making a genuine effort to settle a dispute; that communication cannot be used by the other party as evidence of a concession or waiver of a right.

Comment: Thanks @DaleM but this doesn't cover when the person who signs such a document, adds the phrase 'without prejudice' manually next to the signature.(Assuming the phrase is not already on the document)  Would this still be acceptable by a valid court (in this example)?

Comment: This should not matter provided the phrase was added contemporaneously with the signature - as far as a court is concerned the author of a document is the person who signed it (or their organisation), not the person who drafted it.